# 3G EVDO USB modem speed limited on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, usb-modem, 3g

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a HP dv6 laptop.

I connect to the Internet via a 3G EVDO USB modem (CDMA) of Capitel make from BSNL Kolkata, device id 1c9e:9e00. Making this modem get detected by Ubuntu needs an extra step since Ubuntu 12.04. I have to type in at the terminal: `sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9e00` and after waiting a bit the modem shows up in the Network Manager list, from where I use Edit Connections to type in the username and password.

The modem does connect to the internet but this time I noticed that the speed is limited to 123 kBps instead of the 300 kBps that I get when using Windows 7 or Windows 8.

This problem was not there, as far as I am aware, in previous versions of Ubuntu. This speed limitation of 123 kBps also exists in Linux Mint 17 (both Cinnamon and Mate).

How do I go about diagnosing what is actually causing this 3G modem to limit its speed to 123 kBps when used in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method for my BSNL EVDO (PRITHIVI UE100):
First connect the device to your laptop/PC.
Run the command

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

There should be a device ls /dev/ttyACM0 (or a name similar to that)
To verify, remove the device and run ls /dev/tty* again to check that device has vanished :)

Now you need a nifty program called 'wvdial'
install it using

```
sudo apt-get install wvdial
```

After wvdial has been installed we need to provide a configuration file for wvdial. Create one using

```
sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
```

Enter the following data into the file

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 460800
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0
ISDN = 0
Phone = #777
Password = xxxxxxxxxx
Username = xxxxxxxxxx
Stupid Mode = 1
```

If your username and password are the mobile numbers (then replace xxxxxxxxxx with your device mobile number with prefix-91 for example 91xxxxxxxxxx)

If you don't  know username and password, or the above do not work then you can use this ... (I have used it)

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 460800
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0
ISDN = 0
Phone = #777
Password = 165
Username = 165
Stupid Mode = 1
```

Now run this command (2-3 minutes after you have plugged in the device) to ensure this is working

```
sudo wvdial
```

It should show some DNS servers, (your notification area won't show any connected network) . Open browser and see if pages load. If it does, and I believe it will, then it's good to go.
Now if you are a geek you can just enter sudo wvdial every time to connect, but for people you prefer the comfort of mouse clicks you have some more jobs left to do.

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/bsnl
```

enter this data into that file

```
gksudo wvdial
```

Now we need to set execution permissions to the file

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/bsnl
```

Now we will create a desktop shortcut.

```
gedit ~/Desktop/BSNL.desktop
```

and enter this data into the file

```
 [Desktop Entry]
Name=BSNL EVDO Connection
Exec=bsnl
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
Icon=package_network
```

and make it executable

```
chmod 777 ~/Desktop/BSNL.desktop
```

Now everytime you plug in the device, wait for 1-2 minutes, then double click the brand new icon on your desktop, and woot!! you are online :)

cheers